# Changing between items in drawer menu android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am developing a drawermenu like this:
[image]

and I wrote the code up to the final stages. that is what I have:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class drawermenu extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_points) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_coupons) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

now I want to be able to switch between menu items.
how should I do it? should I have a fragment for each one?
can anyone give me details on how I can do it based on my code?

Comment: Yes, you should use fragment for that. Because for other screen you do not need to create activities. My suggestion is that you should use fragment for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's depends on what you want to do on the MainMenu activity, if you want to jump to another activity to handle more function inside or just display any layout with those menus.

if it's do another function :

> start any new activity each Menus

if it's just displaying data

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment=null;
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        // Handle the camera action
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_points) {
      fragment = new PointFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_coupons) {
      fragment = new CouponFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
      fragment = new AboutFragment();
    }
    fragmentTransaction.replace(containerId, fragment,fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use fragments in your activity when you're using navigationView for your app's top level navigation.

This is right ..

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

and..

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        // Handle the camera action
        getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(containerId, yourFragmentInstance).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_points) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_coupons) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

This is how you replace the fragments

```
getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(containerId, yourFragmentInstance).commit();
```

Comment: I get this error: cannot resolve         getSuppoertFragmentManager

Comment: @user6485186 typo error. `getSupportFragmentManager().`

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Check out my activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toogle;
    private ListView navList;
    private SwitchCompat langSwitch;
    private DashBoardCompanyInfoModel mDashBoardCompanyInfoModel;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu_list_view_list);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        langSwitch = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.lang_switch);
        Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
        if (current.getLanguage().equalsIgnoreCase("nl")) {
            langSwitch.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            langSwitch.setChecked(false);
        }
        switchColor(langSwitch.isChecked());
        langSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                switchColor(b);
                changeLanguage();
                final Intent refresh = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(refresh);
                finish();
            }
        });


        toogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toogle);
        toogle.syncState();


        final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        toogle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Utils.hideSoftKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        initComponent();
        setUpDrawer();
        replaceFragment(new DashboardFragment());
    }


    private void switchColor(boolean checked) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            langSwitch.getThumbDrawable().setColorFilter(checked ? Color.WHITE : Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            final int color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.temp_login);
            langSwitch.getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        }
    }

    private void setUpDrawer() {
        View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_view, null);
        navList.addHeaderView(header);
        final ArrayList<NavigationMenuModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
        final NavigationMenuModel model = new NavigationMenuModel();
        model.setMenuName(getString(R.string.about_us));
        model.setMenuResource(R.drawable.ic_info_white);
        data.add(model);
        final NavigationMenuModel model1 = new NavigationMenuModel();
        model1.setMenuName(getString(R.string.contact_us));
        model1.setMenuResource(R.drawable.ic_email_white);
        data.add(model1);

        final NavigationMenuModel model2 = new NavigationMenuModel();
        model2.setMenuName(getString(R.string.log_out));
        model2.setMenuResource(R.drawable.ic_logout);
        data.add(model2);

        final NavigationListAdapter adapter = new NavigationListAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
        navList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        navList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 1:
                        addContactUsAndAboutUsFragment(getString(R.string.about_us));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        addContactUsAndAboutUsFragment(getString(R.string.contact_us));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        displayLogoutDialog();
                        break;

                }
            }
        });


    }

    private void initComponent() {

    }

    public void addFragment(final Fragment newFragment, final Fragment hideFragment) {
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.content_main_container, newFragment, newFragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .hide(hideFragment)
                .addToBackStack(hideFragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .commit();
    }

    public void replaceFragment(final Fragment newFragment) {
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_main_container, newFragment, newFragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .commit();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (toogle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Utils.hideSoftKeyboard(this);
                if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
//            break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void setToolBar(String title, boolean back_flag) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        toolbar.getMenu().clear();
        if (back_flag) {
            toogle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        } else {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            toogle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);

        }


    }

    private void addContactUsAndAboutUsFragment(final String title) {
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.KEY_WEB_VIEW_TITLE, title);
        final AboutUsFragment aboutUsFragment = new AboutUsFragment();
        aboutUsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        addFragment(aboutUsFragment, getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_main_container));
    }


    public Toolbar getToolbar() {
        return toolbar;
    }


    private void displayLogoutDialog() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        dialog.setMessage(R.string.logout_message);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.dialog_yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                final PreferenceUtils preferenceUtils = new PreferenceUtils(MainActivity.this);
                preferenceUtils.clearPreference();
                final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.dialog_no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    public DashBoardCompanyInfoModel getmDashBoardCompanyInfoModel() {
        return mDashBoardCompanyInfoModel;
    }

    public void setmDashBoardCompanyInfoModel(DashBoardCompanyInfoModel mDashBoardCompanyInfoModel) {
        this.mDashBoardCompanyInfoModel = mDashBoardCompanyInfoModel;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        changeLanguage();
    }

    private void changeLanguage() {
        if (langSwitch.isChecked()) {
            final Locale myLocale = new Locale("nl");
            final Resources res = getResources();
            final DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            final Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.locale = myLocale;
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        } else {
            final Locale myLocale = new Locale("en");
            final Resources res = getResources();
            final DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            final Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.locale = myLocale;
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        }
    }
```